# Sending the result (surveys) in a telegram?

Tags: javascript, ajax, telegram

Created a questionnaire in the service https://surveyjs.io. The result is given in the format

The results are:

`{"question1":["item1"],"question2":["item2"],"question3":["item2"],"question4":["item2"],"question5":["item2"],"question6":"123","test":"123","text":"item1"}`

How to correctly parse this output and send it formatted in telegram?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I don't understand how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` to convert strings to objects and vice versa:

```
const jsonString = '{"question1":["item1"],"question2":["item2"],"question3":["item2"],"question4":["item2"],"question5":["item2"],"question6":"123","test":"123","text":"item1"}';

const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

const processedJsonObject = whateverYouWantToDo(jsonObject);

const outputString = JSON.stringify(processedJsonObject);
```

Comment: and how to send the received data in the form of JSON via ajax to php?

Comment: `fetch(url, { method:"POST", ...`, where url is your PHP page.